# How to get all records which meet a Criteria in Laravel Tinker?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, tinker

I can get the first user, who is an admin in Laravel's tinker using the following command:

`$adminUser = App\User::where('is_admin',true)->first();`

How do I get all the users which meet this where criteria?

Comment: `App\User::where('is_admin',true)->get();`

Comment: first() method will only call single row. get() will call all the matching rows.

Comment: @Arun can you post it as an answer? Is there a document with all such commands?

Comment: laravel documentation is the right place buddy

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe, read these  `https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries`. eloquent supports all the methods in query builder

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Laravel Tinker is an application which is just used to check and test the data. So there is no documentation for that. And as per your question you are just testing so this is common that you don't have to write `$adminUser = App\User::where('is_admin',true)->first();`. just write `App\User::where('is_admin',true)->first();`. I think this is not the answer for this you can delete this question if you find it was common thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change `first()` to `get()`.

`$adminUser = App\User::where('is_admin',true)->get();`

`first()` is used when you want to retrieve single row or column. where `get()` is used to retrieve all rows.

just go through the laravel official documentation database query builder section [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries). It will give you information regarding most of every possible things you can playoff with laravel.

Answer (score 2):

```
$users = App\User::where("is_admin", true)->get();
```

The get method returns an Illuminate\Support\Collection containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP StdClass object. You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
}
```

Src: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

In case of Tinker, things in Query builder and Eloquent docs will work in Tinker. It exists for the purpose of instantly getting the result without debugging using your real application.

Answer (score 0):

The `first()` function is used when you want to retrieve single row, whereas the `get()` function is used to retrieve all matching rows.

```
$adminUser = App\User::where('is_admin', true)->get();
dd($adminUser);
```